# SVG - Draw multiple circles with a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm new to HTML5 programming. I have done this so far on my project for university: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvpZQ.jpg

Basically, I've drawn 4 circles to form an image, and now I have to code that big image in order to make 10 little images per line with a slider, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okWaw.jpg

The slider only needs to work when I press the button.

My code:

```
<svg id="vect"  width="500" height="500"><svg/>

function circletop(x,y,r,esp,cor){
     vect.innerHTML+=
            '<circle cx="'+x+'" cy="'+y+'" r="'+r+'" stroke-width="'+esp+'" stroke="'+cor+'" fill="#013D55" />';
     }
     function circlebot(x,y,r,esp,cor){
     vect.innerHTML+=
            '<circle cx="'+x+'" cy="'+y+'" r="'+r+'" stroke-width="'+esp+'" stroke="'+cor+'" fill="#013D55" />';
     }

     function circleRight(x,y,r,esp,cor){
    vect.innerHTML+=
            '<circle cx="'+x+'" cy="'+y+'" r="'+r+'" stroke-width="'+esp+'" stroke="'+cor+'" fill="#AA8D49" />';
     }
     function circleLeft(x,y,r,esp,cor){
     vect.innerHTML+=
            '<circle cx="'+x+'" cy="'+y+'" r="'+r+'" stroke-width="'+esp+'" stroke="'+cor+'" fill="#AA8D49" />';
     }
```

I combined it all on a single function:

```
function svgBigPicture(){
    circlebop(250,500,225,50,"#449779");
    circleright(0,250,225,50,"#E6B569");
    circleleft(500,250,225,50,"#E6B569");
    circletop(250,0,225,50,"#449779");
```

How do I use this to make many circles per line? I can't use jQuery, has to be 100% JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit more of a pattern and I think the way to are approaching this is odd - SVG is nice, yes, but writing using `innerHTML` seems a bit.. Like cheating. I know the following solution does not use SVG for this, but consider using `canvas` for a possible solution:

```js
var CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas');
var CTX = CANVAS.getContext('2d');

function draw(x, y, radius){
  CANVAS.width = x * radius * 2;
  CANVAS.height = y * radius;
  // Because canvas draws on top, we want to start at the bottom!
  for(var Y = y; Y >= -1; Y--)
  for(var X = x; X >= -1; X--){
    CTX.beginPath();
    CTX.arc(X * radius * 2 + (Y%2?radius:0), Y * radius, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    CTX.strokeStyle = Y%2 ? 'red' : 'blue';
    CTX.fillStyle = '#fff';
    CTX.stroke();
    CTX.fill();
    CTX.closePath();
  }
}

draw(5,5,50)

var INPUT = document.getElementById('input');
INPUT.addEventListener('change', function(){
  draw(parseInt(this.value, 10), parseInt(this.value, 10) + 1, 50)
});
```

```css
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input id="input" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" />
```

Using SVG with JS is just not the best match... JS has difficulties reading contents of the SVG tag and you're making more problems for yourself. If you really want to go down this path the suggestion is to have a look at `defs` and `pattern` definitions for SVG, heres some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. This "project" is for my university, I would like to use the things you suggested but I can't. My professor doesn't want us to use jQuery or Patterns, has to be JavaScript, and that's why I can't do it, we are force to do with innerHTML, I didn't even know that defs or patterns existed to be honest. Thanks for taking your time and replying.

Comment: @ricardoreis Uhm, what I posted is pure javascript, no jQuery, no plugins. Canvas is like SVG in that regard, as its a JS API built in to your browser. The above requires nothing but a browser with HTML5 support. I would even go as far as to say that this is _purer_ javascript than using innerHTML to fake an SVG.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention, we can't use Canvas in this situation because that's for the other project we have to do for him. We have two projects, one in canvas and one in SVG. I've done the Canvas one and its fully working. This project is the only one I can't get my head around it

Comment: Good luck then,i'm not overly familiar with handcrafting svgs using javascript, so sorry i cant help more!